# Newly installed MySQL Server requires password

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-20.04

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running within virtualbox and run a mysql-server on it. I removed the old mysql-server and reinstalled it using

```
sudo apt remove mysql-server
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

Following the tutorial on [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04) I tried to run `sudo mysql_secure_installation` but the script asks for a password.

Also when using the mysql-client I get the following output:

```
userone@userone-VirtualBox:~$ sudo mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I tried several times do remove and reinstall using

```
sudo apt remove --purge mysql-server
```

but I keep getting the password request dialog. Hitting Return without providing a password raises the following error:

```
userone@userone-VirtualBox:~$ sudo mysql_secure_installation 

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Anybody an idea why the password is required for a new installation?

- Ubuntu 20.04
- MySQL 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

Edit: It seems the password for my freshly installed mysql-server was root as well? Is this something I set as password in a previous installation and wasn't completely removed when purging or is this new to mysql-server? I remember the default password was blank on previous installations.
Also all my previous test databases are still available, I expected them to be gone when unistalling mysql-server.

Edit: I manually delteted

```
/var/lib/mysql
/var/lib/mysql-files
/var/lib/mysql-keyring
/var/lib/mysql-update
```

it still requires a password only now it won't accept my old password anymore

Answer (score 0):

To begin the removal process, navigate to Settings from the Start menu and then choose Apps.
Search for sql in the search box.
SQL Server (Version) (Bit). ...
Select Uninstall/Change.
Select Remove on the SQL Server dialog pop-up to launch the SQL Server installation wizard.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean with Start menu / Apps. Is this for Windows or Ubuntu? I'm using a Ubuntu server.